# I want to get all data in elasticsearch 5.4

Tags: elasticsearch

I used `size :0` in `Elasticsearch 2.x` but now in `Elasticsearch 5.4` this can not be used.

How do I get the same effect as `size: 0` in `Elasticsearch 5.4` ?

Comment: "size" is used in multiple places in Elasticsearch - which one are you referring to? for example is it the number of results to return to a user or in aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

The size:0 was [deprecated](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18838) in Elasticsearch 5.x aggregations. You can check https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22136 for workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

Use ES's snapshot and restore instead :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

Do note that a snapshot of an index created in 1.X cannot be restored to 5.X

Comment: My issue is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/breaking_50_aggregations_changes.html#_literal_size_0_literal_on_terms_significant_terms_and_geohash_grid_aggregations

Your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: Please change the title of the question from 'I want to get all data in elasticsearch 5.4' and be more specific in the question text then